# Oracle 11g Express connection string editing

Tags: string, oracle, connection

I am new to Oracle Express and to `connection strings`.  I have searched the net for where the `connections strings` are located but have no clue.  Also, when editing such to connect to a remote database, if I was supplied the strings to use, would I just simply copy and paste them in and the database should show up?

Comment: I discovered the location under oracle installation folder as `C:\[oracle main folder]\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN` and the file is called tnsnames.ora

Comment: [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) has the information you need. With ODP.NEt, you don't need a TNSNAMES.ORA to make your connection.